# Problem with Set Precision

Tags: list-manipulation, precision-and-accuracy

I am using Set Precision to calculate data point pairs (t,Y) in a table:
Table[{t, SetPrecision[test[t], 4]}, {t, 0, 135, 7}],
Works fine until I try to copy and paste the list into another list elsewhere in my Notebook / Manipulate. Soon as I complete the copy and paste, the new list of numbers expands out to like 18 decimal places with the number 4 at the end of each Y value. What am I doing wrong? I want 4 significant figures. I do not want 18 significant figures.

Comment: Copy as plain text, either from menu or shortcut  (e.g. ctrl-shift-c on windows).

Comment: I think you do want those extra digits. Or you don't want to be using `SetPrecision`.  There's not enough information in the question for me to decide.  If you do want `SetPrecision`, then what you are seeing is the difference between `InputForm` and `OutputForm`.  Arbitrary-precision numbers always have extra digits in their internal representation (the min. is 64 bits or ~19 digits, I think).  You might want `Round` or `NumberForm` instead. Idk.

Comment: "Real World' data in my current project would only read out to three or perhaps four decimal places. I am wanting to use NonLinearModelFit on a list of data points where each point set (Y value, dependent variable) would read out to three or perhaps four decimal places.

Comment: @HenryB The fact that the input data has only few significant digits should not prevent you performing computations in higher precision. In particular be because computations in finite precision other than `MachinePrecision` are significantly slower than in `MachinePrecision`, because they have to be emulated in software.  Best practice would probably be to do the computations in `MachinePrecision` and to round the output to the desired precision.